# redirect a set of URLs to another URL with part of the original in the new URLs parameters

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, ubuntu-server

Say I have a set of URLs

`Http://www.example.com/some/thing/*`
Call the bit in the star, $id

And I want it to simply return the file at `http://www.example.com/some/thing.html?src=$id` without telling the client its a new URL.

After some research I have been told to set up a .htaccess file, however, Ubuntu suggests that is a bad idea and that I should do it through the main configuration. I dont mind doing it either way. However, its worth noting, that for so e reason I don't have a default.conf file in my `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

Answer (score 0):

Enable .htaccess if it is not already enabled and then you can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^some/thing/(.+)$ some/thing.html?src=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: would document root be something like `/var/www`? as well, how do i enable .htaccess. i've looked here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles but i don't have a `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`. I do however have a `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default` but it doesn't have any `allowOverride None` configuration in it already.

Comment: Sorry I don't have Ubuntu system to check this but to  Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?